# How to stream 301 redirect from ws client in play framework

Tags: java, http, redirect, playframework, ws-client

I am a writing a middleware program, where it internally calls third party api. The third party api responds with 301 including some headers. I have respond with response i got to front end. Is there any piece of code sample which will do this?

Comment: A 301 code means Moved Permanently. Do you need to follow the redirect or just to bypass the response to consumer?

Comment: I just to bypass the response to consumer

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I do not see other options rather than building the response object setting the headers.

```
public Result proxy() {
  response().setHeader(myHeader, headerValue1);
  // all your custom headers
  return status(Http.Status.MOVED_PERMANENTLY, "response body").as(your media type);
}
```

Comment: But this wont redirect the consumer with the redirect url i got it from my wsclient 301 response

Comment: sorry, but why not? As long as you're passing `location` header and indicating with `301` as response code, your client should be able to follow the redirect.